# Parsing MultipartFile data to string in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to parse the MultipartFile data to string and return the string as response in java springboot. Can anyone suggest the right approach for this?

**controller.java**

```
@POST
@Path("/modelInfo")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public Response getPretrainedModel(MultipartFile data) throws IOException {
    String content = new String(data.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(content).build();
}
```

**file.json**

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "text": "abc"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am sending file.json in request body as multipart/form-data and I want to read the content of the file and store it as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spring and Spring Boot, then you are not using the proper annotation. Spring does not support `Jax-RS` specification. Therefor, change your annotations for this one:

```
//    @POST
//    @Path("/modelInfo")
//    @Produces({ "application/json" })
@PostMapping(value = "/modelInfo", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Then, to return an object, you can just return the object in the method:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/modelInfo", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String getPretrainedModel(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile data) throws IOException {
    String content = new String(data.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return content;
}
```

Note:

- Don't forget to add the annotation `@RequestParam` in your method parameter to get the uploaded file. The name `file` must be the name of the attribute uploaded by your POST request
- By default, the HTTP Response is 200 when you don't tell Spring to send something else.
- If you want to override that, annotate your method with `@ResponseStatus`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Just wanted to know apart from MultipartFile, is there any other way to read the content of the file sent through request body form-data?